# How to create a roadway using a topo values shapefile (survey points data) in Sketchup Pro?

Tags: land-survey, sketchup

I am a GIS Technician, new to Sketchup, I would like to know how to create a roadway in Sketchup Pro using a shapefile which is a survey points data with elevations in meters.

The topographic data is georeferenced and has XYZ values for each point surveyed at an interval of 5 meters (vertical) and at 3 cross section locations horizotally on the road.

The resulting 3D model should respect these values at specified locations.